# Occasional printing with inkjet

Tags: inkjet-printer

I am looking for an inkjet that will allow occasional printing without having problems with the printer heads clogging.  I do most of my printing with my laser jet but keep a multifuction printer for scanning and printing in color when needed.  Now I have to spend long period of time cleaning the jets before I can get a good picture.  I am now ready to purchase a new printer and am looking for suggestions.

Comment: Hi there. This isn't a question. :) Even if taken as such, it would be a shopping recommendation request, and therefore off-topic for SU.  Perhaps check out [Best way to save ink in inkjet printer when rarely used?](http://superuser.com/questions/198005/best-way-to-save-ink-in-inkjet-printer-when-rarely-used) and [How to revive an inkjet printer — partially clogged/dried up?](http://superuser.com/questions/55907/how-to-revive-an-inkjet-printer-partially-clogged-dried-up)